# Tracking GitHub commits using RSS

Tags: rss, github

I'm monitoring the commit log of a project my team is working on, and I was wondering whether there's any way to view the commits in an RSS/Atom reader.

I.e., is there any URL provided by GitHub that simply outputs the commit log in a format readable by an RSS/Atom reader?

Answer (score 10):

You only really need to add `.atom` to the end of most branch views to get the corresponding RSS feed of its commits.

```
https://github.com/{username}/{repo}/commits/master.atom
```

The above will show the RSS feed for commits against the master branch. If you wanted to see commits for another branch, change accordingly:

```
https://github.com/{username}/{repo}/commits/{branch-name}.atom
```

Comment: What if I want the RSS feed to include the full (syntax-highlighted) commit diff?

Answer (score 0):

Right after I posted this, I decided to simply try providing the URL for a specific branch and seeing what happens (e.g., the [Linux master branch](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits/master)). Turns out that [feedly](http://feedly.com/) was able to read that, no problem. So, problem solved.